# Cortex M, gcc - faster bounding in C

Tags: c, gcc, cortex-m, thumb

I am trying to bound a difference between 2 integers in c; essentially  absolute value ( a- b) < bound.  Does anyone know, for the Arm Cortex gcc compiler if I am better off taking the absolute value of a difference:

```
  if (abs( a - b) < bound)
    {
      .........
    }
```

or if I should make two compares:

```
    int diff;
    diff = a - b;
    if ((bound > diff) && (bound > -diff))
    {
     .......
    }
```

I know that this has a lot to do with compiler optimization and the Arm instruction set so it is not something I can casually determine.

Comment: "this has a lot to do with compiler optimization" - right, you should leave it to the compiler to figure out

Comment: what about  `diff = a > b ? a-b : b-a;`

Answer (score 1):

Just try it

```
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int fun0 ( int a, int b, int bound )
{
    if (abs( a - b) < bound)
    {
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
unsigned int fun1 ( int a, int b, int bound )
{
    int diff;
    diff = a - b;
    if ((bound > diff) && (bound > (-diff)))
    {
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( int a, int b, int bound )
{
    int diff;
    diff = a > b ? a-b : b-a;
    if(diff < bound)
    {
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

one version of gcc

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   1a40        subs    r0, r0, r1
   2:   2800        cmp r0, #0
   4:   bfb8        it  lt
   6:   4240        neglt   r0, r0
   8:   4290        cmp r0, r2
   a:   bfac        ite ge
   c:   2000        movge   r0, #0
   e:   2001        movlt   r0, #1
  10:   4770        bx  lr
  12:   bf00        nop

00000014 <fun1>:
  14:   1a41        subs    r1, r0, r1
  16:   4291        cmp r1, r2
  18:   da05        bge.n   26 <fun1+0x12>
  1a:   4249        negs    r1, r1
  1c:   4291        cmp r1, r2
  1e:   bfac        ite ge
  20:   2000        movge   r0, #0
  22:   2001        movlt   r0, #1
  24:   4770        bx  lr
  26:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  28:   4770        bx  lr
  2a:   bf00        nop

0000002c <fun2>:
  2c:   4288        cmp r0, r1
  2e:   bfcc        ite gt
  30:   1a40        subgt   r0, r0, r1
  32:   1a08        suble   r0, r1, r0
  34:   4290        cmp r0, r2
  36:   bfac        ite ge
  38:   2000        movge   r0, #0
  3a:   2001        movlt   r0, #1
  3c:   4770        bx  lr
  3e:   bf00        nop
```

fun0 and fun2 are the same number of instructions no branches, takes advantage of conditional execution (without that the results may have a clear winner).  The middle one, your alternative, incurs a branch but has a path that is shorter so hard to call it a loser in this case.  9 or 5 instructions (including branch) compared to 9 and 9.

Different targets, the results may be different.

Another approach:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int funct(int a, int b, int bound, int c)
{
  if (abs(a-b) < bound) c = 5;

    return c;
}
int funct2(const int a, const int b, const int bound, int c)
{
    int diff;
    diff = a > b ? a-b : b-a;
    if ((bound > diff) && (bound > -diff)) c = 4;
    return c;
}
00000000 <funct>:
   0:   1a40        subs    r0, r0, r1
   2:   2800        cmp r0, #0
   4:   bfb8        it  lt
   6:   4240        neglt   r0, r0
   8:   4290        cmp r0, r2
   a:   bfac        ite ge
   c:   4618        movge   r0, r3
   e:   2005        movlt   r0, #5
  10:   4770        bx  lr
  12:   bf00        nop

00000014 <funct2>:
  14:   4288        cmp r0, r1
  16:   bfcc        ite gt
  18:   1a41        subgt   r1, r0, r1
  1a:   1a09        suble   r1, r1, r0
  1c:   4291        cmp r1, r2
  1e:   da03        bge.n   28 <funct2+0x14>
  20:   4249        negs    r1, r1
  22:   4291        cmp r1, r2
  24:   bfb8        it  lt
  26:   2304        movlt   r3, #4
  28:   4618        mov r0, r3
  2a:   4770        bx  lr
```

The second solution has a path with fewer instructions but incurs a branch, the other path is longer.

Comment: how you choose to implement the test function and then optimize that can affect the results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both are Undefined Behaviours. The substraction may overflow. You need to check as @e2-e4  mentioned in the comment which is larger and substract. It will be nicely optimized by the gcc.

```
int funct(int a, int b, int bound, int c)
{
  if (abs(a > b ? a-b : b-a) < bound) c = 5;

    return c;
}

int funct2(const int a, const int b, const int bound, int c) 
{
    int diff;
    diff = a > b ? a-b : b-a;
    if ((bound > diff) && (bound > -diff)) c = 4;
    return c;
}
```

Both compile the exactly the same code.

Comment: BTW it still can overflow

Comment: why defeat the abs?  The question was to compare abs to something else.  I dont seem them producing the same code when the abs is used.